# How to create consecutive named files

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I need to create `files.txt` with `10 lines` and with a name like `10FRE001 then 10FRE002`, got it? How may I do that ? How check if there's 10 lines already and how to increment the name from `10FRE001` to `10FRE002` ? 
To check if there's 10 lines already I thought use a `int counter++;` i'll see... But I have no idea of how work with the files name... Any tips ? Thanks everyone

This is what I code so far, it read and write a new text file, but I have no idea on how change the names of the files...

```
string conteudo="";
int numeroLinhas=0;

using(var writer=new StreamWriter(Txt_DestinoPath.Text, true))
using(var reader=new StreamReader(Txt_OrigemPath.Text)) {
    while(reader.ReadLine()!=null)
        numeroLinhas++;

    string oi=numeroLinhas.ToString();

    writer.WriteLine(oi);
    int contador=0;

    for(int i=0; i<numeroLinhas; i++) {
        if(contador<9) {
            contador++;
            writer.WriteLine(@"\campo0"+contador+@"\");
        }
        else {
            contador++;
            writer.WriteLine(@"\campo"+contador+@"\");
        }
    }
}

using(var sw=new StreamWriter(Txt_DestinoPath.Text, true))
using(var sr=new StreamReader(Txt_OrigemPath.Text))
    while((conteudo=sr.ReadLine())!=null) {
        // Tira asteriscos,remove valor vazio, insere barras 
        string[] teste=conteudo.Split(new[] { '*' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        var noEmptyParts=
            teste
                .Where(p => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p))
                .Skip(2)
                .Select(p => String.Format("\\{0}\\", p.Trim()))
                .ToArray<String>();

        string resultado=String.Join("", noEmptyParts);

        if(Txt_DestinoPath.Text==""||Txt_DestinoPath.Text==string.Empty) {
            MessageBox.Show("Nenhum Caminho de Origem Escolhido.");
            return;
        }

        // Cria novo arquivo txt                
        sw.WriteLine(resultado);
    }
```

The result of the counter above is: `\campo01\, \campo02\, \campo03\ .... \campo10\, \campo11\ ...`

The name I need to change i'll place it on

```
Txt_DestinoPath.Text + FileThatIneedToIncrement,true)
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: And to dovetail off what JG in SD just said, post some code if you have it.

Comment: I created 2 `StreamReader` and 2 `StreamWriter` I tried to create a counter and increment it ´counter++` But its not working with the names... The `001` -> `002` part... =\

Comment: Convert `int` to `string` & concat with other part of the string prior to use?

Comment: Edited: I tried the same thing I've done above. Check if the first number is > 9 then I'll increment the other number... But I couldn't make it. I need change these files name to put it on the StreamWriter's path... Hope I could be clear

Comment: Ken Kin, I'd like to ask you to do not edit my answer the way that I didnt write just because you think it's "more beautiful"... It should be the way I wrote so you all can understand what is wrong and what isnt... If you think the way you wrote is better than mine, post it as an answer saying why... Not editing what I've done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do 10FRE001, 10FRE002, ... naming you can try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
    string fileName = string.Format("10FRE{0:D3}",i);
    // other codes
}
```

Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx), and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Comment: I'll try it right now... Could you just explain me the `{0:D3}` part? Thanks

Comment: I'll just make some tests and as soon as I finish here, i'll mark it as the answer...